# Tornado 405 error POST method not allowed

Tags: php, python, html, tornado

I am trying to make a php login into tornado and when I click "Sign in" I am getting a page with an error saying "405 Method not allowed".

Here is my form:

```
<form method="POST">

          <fieldset id="inputs">
            <input name="username" id="username" required>   
            <input name="password" id="password" type="password" name="Password" placeholder="Password" required>
          </fieldset>
          <fieldset id="actions">
            <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Log in" name="submit">
            <label><input type="checkbox" checked="checked"> Keep me signed in</label>
          </fieldset>

        </form>
```

Comment: What is the action attribute of the form? If you sent POST to a wrong URL, you may get this "Method Not Allowed" error.

Comment: Did you specify the `action` attribute to the right location?

Comment: Yes I tried, but still same.

Comment: should the url be a link to the page i want the user to be in or some other page that connects with the db?

Comment: It would be helpful if you included your server-side code.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add an action to your form and have a post method  in your handler. If you set up a handler like:

```
(r"/feedback", FeedbackHandler)
```

Which has a post method:

```
def post(self):
    #do something here
```

And a form which has:

```
<form action="/feedback" method="post" >
```

It should work.